# iOS - How to deal with bonded devices in BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have interract with a BLE device using an iOS App. These devices are bonded.

The problem appears when I go to Settings and I press 'Forget Device'. The application keeps trying to connect even though the device was forgotten because on the "peripheral:didDisconnect" callback I try to reconnect to the device. The bluetooth device sends a disconnect event because the bond is not good anymore. Then the application tries again a connection and so on.

I tried to look at the error code in the "peripheral:didDisconnect:" but It did not look very relevant.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using this callback:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

The error looks like this:

```
Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=15 "Encryption is insufficient." UserInfo=0x170272f40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Encryption is insufficient.}
```